# PHP Get DIV Contents From DOM Using Xpath

Tags: php, regex, dom, xpath

I'm trying to get the contents of a DIV from a DOM object, I'm using the below code. `$url` is a valid string url and if I drop it in a browser it opens a page that contains the DIV I'm looking for.

`$url` is a string for example like:

```
$url = 'http://api.testdev.com/testpage.html';
```

**Code**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$rawData = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, \'listing-products\')]');
```

The HTML code I'm trying to target below using the regex `//div[contains(@class, \'listing-products\')]`:

```
<div class="listing-products right-content">
```

I'm just getting an empty array like below, no errors in the logs, on screen or in the browser console.

```
DOMNodeList Object
{
     [length] => 0
}
```

I suspect my regex pattern isn't 100% correct, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Use the double-quotes, instead of single-quotes?

Comment: @stribizhev, you only have a single class in your example, there are multiple classes in the div where it's not working for me.

Comment: [It works with multiple classes, too](http://ideone.com/iSOWFS).

Comment: @stribizhev, figured it out, you are correct the code is working, I was passing a string into the `loadHTML` function instead of the actual HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that where I was using `$dom->loadHTML` I was passing in a URL string instead of the HTML that the function expects, to fix this I've wrapped the `$url` variable with the `file_get_contents` function which has fixed the problem.

Old Code:

```
$dom->loadHTML($url);
```

New, working Code:

```
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
```